# ESP32 reboots constantly due to "flash read err, 1000"

Tags: esp32

Folks, I couldn't decide if this is on or off-topic, but it feels related to programming.

I've an ESP32 board, embedded into a NodeMCU. I've connected an UART2USB serial monitor directly to the ESP32's RX-TX, and initially this was printed onto serial console after poweron:

```
rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0x00
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3fff0008,len:8
load:0x3fff0010,len:3480
load:0x40078000,len:7804
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load:0x40080000,len:252
entry 0x40080034
I (46) boot: ESP-IDF v2.0-3-gbef9896 2nd stage bootloader
```

I followed Espressif's instructions to build the simplest helloworld program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sdkconfig.h"
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "esp_system.h"
#include "esp_spi_flash.h"

void app_main(void)
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");

    /* Print chip information */
    esp_chip_info_t chip_info;
    esp_chip_info(&chip_info);
    printf("This is %s chip with %d CPU core(s), WiFi%s%s, ",
            CONFIG_IDF_TARGET,
            chip_info.cores,
            (chip_info.features & CHIP_FEATURE_BT) ? "/BT" : "",
            (chip_info.features & CHIP_FEATURE_BLE) ? "/BLE" : "");

    printf("silicon revision %d, ", chip_info.revision);

    printf("%dMB %s flash\n", spi_flash_get_chip_size() / (1024 * 1024),
            (chip_info.features & CHIP_FEATURE_EMB_FLASH) ? "embedded" : "external");

    printf("Minimum free heap size: %d bytes\n", esp_get_minimum_free_heap_size());

    for (int i = 10; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("Restarting in %d seconds...\n", i);
        vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
    printf("Restarting now.\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    esp_restart();
}
```

Also, I did successfully (I believe) compiled and flashed (without errors) this hello world example to ESP32.

After that however, this is printed onto serial monitor:

```
rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
flash read err, 1000
ets_main.c 371 
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
flash read err, 1000
ets_main.c 371 
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57
```

`RTCWDT_RTC_RESET` keeps repeating. Only stops when I cut the power.

As I said, I couldn't decide about "on-topicness" of this question, because I'm not sure if this problematic behavior is some kind of fault in "helloworld" example, or coming from somewhere else.

### Update

I might accidentally erased the bootloader, so I did a `make flash`.

This created a `bootloader.bin` in the build folder, which I tried to flash, but this doesn't change anything.

I'm flashing with https://github.com/espressif/esp-serial-flasher.

Comment: 'make flash' uploads the application with esptool

Comment: I'm compiling on DeviceA, and flashing on DeviceB, so `make flash` only compiled the binaries for me. Although I have realized, that in spite of `make flash` created a nice large `hello_world.bin`, I might have to upload `bootloader.bin` to 0x1000, `partition-table.bin` to 0x8000 and finally my `hello_world.bin` to 0x10000. Can you confirm I'm right with the above please?

Comment: yes that is what make flash does. I think if you run only make, it will print at the  end the esptool command line you can run

Comment: Perfect, now it works as intended. You might want to get some credits, if you add your answer I'll happily accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by

First, erasing flash, this can be done using esptool, or if you use platformio there is a menu under platformio tab -> platform - Erase Flash

command for esptool:

```
python esptool.py --port COMxx --chip esp32 erase_flash
```

Second, Clean and rebuild the code then upload it to your micro.

Hope this will help